# Возможно ли задать 100% ширину фото в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Нужно поставить изображения на полную ширину девайса. У меня есть такая функция

```
function theme_setup(){
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 180, 120, true);
add_image_size('banner-image', 920, 210, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup');
```

Возможно ли задать ширину когда пользователь кликнул на пост и фото должен открыться на полную ширину (100%). Когда в обычном положении размер будет маленьким.

index.php

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></a> <!--фотка -->
</div>
```

single.php

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); ?>
```

[image: вот два картинки] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58950/discussion-on-question-by-duuudexx8----100----wordpr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то вот решение вашей проблемы.

PHP:

```
<div class="banner-image">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); ?> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

На вопрос достаточно точно ответить сложно, потому что автор так и не показал, где и как он выводит саму миниатюру и как он хочет выводить полную картинку.

Если иметь ввиду обычное построение блога на WordPress, то при формировании страницы блога в цикле выводятся заголовки, краткое содержание постов и миниатюры. При клике на пост - отрывается страница поста с полной картинкой. Как это делают? При создании поста картинку большого размера вставляют в пост. И ее же указывают как thumbnail. Никаких add_image_size() при этом не нужно вовсе.

Размер загружаемой картинки зависит от верстки - если это верстка во всю ширину - надо грузить не менее 1920px в ширину. Если ширина колонки вывода поста, скажем, 920px - то и картинку надо грузить 920px.

Размер миниатюры устанавливается в админке, в разделе Настройки->Медиафайлы. Без всякого кода.

И если уж сильно хочется в single.php использовать `the_post_thumbnail()`, и при этом требовать, чтобы картинка выводилась во всю ширину контейнера, то уж никак нельзя при этом указывать урезанный размер типа banner-image. Выводить надо так:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```

Такой размер изображения, существующий всегда по умолчанию, выведет картинку в ее исходном размере, и вы не попадете в ситуацию, когда у вас размер banner-image имеет ширину 920px, ширина контейнера 1500px, картинка растянута и смотреть на нее невозможно.

Comment: А что делать, если заходят посетители с разной шириной экрана? Если контейнер не фиксированный, а резиновый по ширине.

Comment: @shugich если картинка шириной 1920px, а экран 1300px, она и выведется размером 1300px. При полном отсутствии каких-либо правил css.

Comment: А что если кто то зашел к примеру с телевизора представьте еффект картинки 1920 пикселей и по бокам будет белый фон.Вот почему мне нужно ширина 100%.

Comment: С какого еще телевизора? Давайте уже в профессиональных терминах разговаривать. В html и css понятие телевизор, телескоп и прочее - отсутствуют

Comment: Если выводить full и картинка 1920, то без какого-либо CSS на экране шириной 1300 пикселей появится горизонтальная прокрутка.

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо за полезный ответ

Comment: Я вот вообще вангую, что ТСу нужно поставить плагин лайтбокса и всех делов.

Comment: @SeVlad я тоже об этом думал. Но, по-хорошему, вопрос надо закрывать, потому что непонятна его суть.

Comment: @KAGGDesign абсолютно согласен.Я пытался донести до ТСа мысль о важности правильно задавать вопросы, но.. тщетно к сож.

Answer (score 0):

Картинки в WordPress, не расширялись во всю ширину страницы текста, расширить удалось редактированием картинки, как html, удалением последней строки класс.

установил плагин расширяющий стандартный редактор TinyMCE Advanced, в редакторе - редактировать, как html ; удалял класс фотографии в конце записи, дальше ошибка, исправить ошибку, преобразовать в блоки и всё, далее всё в картинках:

http://racuha.ru/o0o0/archives/160[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Привидите пожалуйста  более наглядный пример -- как вам удалось расширить. А то не совсем понятно, например: _удалением последней строки класс_, но ваш ответ не содержит ни оодной строки.